# Getting rid of Future Warning

Tags: python, pandas

```
sunny = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition'] == 'CLR']

overcast = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition'].str.contains('OVC')]

sunny_daily_max = sunny.resample('D').agg(['max'])
overcast_daily_max = overcast.resample('D').agg(['max'])

print(sunny_daily_max.mean(numeric_only=True) - overcast_daily_max.mean(numeric_only=True))
```

I get

```
/tmp/ipykernel_831/2080168548.py:9: FutureWarning: ['visibility'] did not aggregate successfully. If any error is raised this will raise in a future version of pandas. Drop these columns/ops to avoid this warning.
  sunny_daily_max = sunny.resample('D').agg(['max']) /tmp/ipykernel_831/2080168548.py:10: FutureWarning: ['visibility'] did not aggregate successfully. If any error is raised this will raise in a future version of pandas. Drop these columns/ops to avoid this warning.
  overcast_daily_max = overcast.resample('D').agg(['max'])`
```

If i run this code a second time, it works without that. But i need to work it without any warnings from the first time. I would be glad for any possible solution to fix this

Comment: What is the dtype of 'visibility' column in your dataframe?

Comment: you have to fix data in column `visibility` to get rid of this warning. But we have no idea what you have in this column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select_dtypes` to keep only numeric columns:

```
sunny = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition'] == 'CLR'].select_dtypes('number')

overcast = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition'].str.contains('OVC')].select_dtypes('number')
```

If `visibility` should only contain numeric values, you have something wrong in this column. In this case, use:

```
sunny['visibility'] = pd.to_numeric(sunny['visibility'], errors='coerce')


overcast['visibility'] = pd.to_numeric(overcast['visibility'], errors='coerce')
```